# What NoSQL DB should I choose for multi-user project collaboration app?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, redis

I'm trying to develop **iphone app back-end by PHP or Node.js** (which I haven't decided yet). The app will be like **multi-user project collaboration tool**. For example, each user from iPhone can **create a project** and other **invited members** can discuss **how much** they want **to spend** on this particular project. Each user can **add up single cost** and the **server** will handle the **calculation** of **total expense** and update back to all project members. So it's less likely a real-time app but still, alot of updates record and updates needed to be done by the Database.

As far as I googled...

CouchDB is little bit slower than MongoDB and Radis.

MongoDB is fast but there is a chance to loss old data. Since all data must be persistance for my project, shall I rely on MongoDB?

Radis is much faster than those two, but it's such a over-kill for my project and need to spend more time to learn.

Anyway, I still want to hear from those experienced people from here ... what kind of NoSQL DB is best for my scenario?

Comment: Since the project spec is vague and incomplete, the answer is "we don't know". So pick one and try. Doesn't work - pick another. I'd start with MongoDB - it's my DB of choice.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with a traditional RDBMS for this project?

Comment: @Dor, there will be a lot of insert and update events for each "project" event. So I'm afraid MySQL will be the bottleneck when 100 of users on 10 different projects are updating and inserting data and each updates are needed to broadcast to all members of each project. Would that be ok with MySQL? I'm not a MySQL pro so I'm all ear :)

Answer (score 3):

To address some of your concerns:

With MongoDB, durability is given a lower priority to achieve higher levels of performance. It doesn't write data to the disk right away, instead applies bulk changes to the disk. MongoDB enabled [Journaling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair) by default since version 1.9.2 - this means slightly reduced  write performance, but ability to automatically bring the database back to a consistent state during the recovery process. [Replication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication) addresses long term data durability concerns

One cannot generally assume one database to be faster than the others. The benchmarks available online often fail to successfully emulate real world scenarios, much less the case of your particular application

Factors that should help you decide -

- Redis is a Key-value store, MongoDB is a document store. You should try and model your scenario using both of them (You might also want to look at Column stores and relational databases). Pick the one that models your data more easily than the others. If a particular database requires you to do really complex queries (for your scenario), you will want to avoid that
- NoSQL systems generally require - you, as a user, to understand how it works to a deeper abstraction level than the relational ones. Various systems have their own tradeoffs to achieve certain goals (like performance or durability). You should understand these and be prepared to get your hands dirty
- When in trouble, you might want access to help. Prefer those with good documentation and an active developer community (or readily available commercial support)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer Elvis. I had some experience with CouchDB and due to my lack of knowledge, I'm not quite comfortable creating queries with CouchDB. After trying out MongoDB, I may wrong, it offers  more flexible querying style with ease. Does that happen to u as well?

Comment: I have negligible experience with couchdb, but yeah, I've come across situations where queries to a datastore feel a lot natural as against another.